# strange routing table after PXE boot WinPE

Tags: routing, pxe-boot, windows-pe

I have a pxe boot WinPE using iPXE, iPXE config file as follow:

```
sanhook iscsi:10.86.13.52::::iqn.2003-01.org.linux-iscsi.htpc.x8664:sn.d2a44be19814
cpuid --ext 29 && set arch amd64 || set arch x86
kernel http://10.86.13.52/ISO/wimboot
initrd http://10.86.13.52/ISO/bootmgr      bootmgr
initrd http://10.86.13.52/ISO/bcd          BCD
initrd http://10.86.13.52/ISO/boot.sdi     boot.sdi
initrd http://10.86.13.52/ISO/winpe.wim    boot.wim
boot
```

After I successfully boot into PE, I found that I can't connect to my iSCSI target, can't even ping the IP. Then I found the strange routing table, below:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.86.13.254     10.86.13.149     30
       10.86.13.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      10.86.13.149    286
     10.86.13.149  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.86.13.149    286
     10.86.13.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.86.13.149    286
     10.86.13.52   255.255.255.255     10.86.13.254     10.86.13.149    286
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.86.13.149    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.86.13.149    286
```

Please note the line with 10.86.13.52, how does it go into routing table? I didn't set it in my dhcp server. I tried to delete it using:

```
route delete 10.86.13.52
and 
route delete 10.86.13.52 mask 255.255.255.255
```

but both failed, saying can't find the item.

Any idea?

Comment: Your `sanhook` statement will attach the SAN as a BIOS drive. How are you trying to "connect to your iSCSI target"? It would probably be easiest to drop that statement and attach the iSCSI target with the `iscsicpl` command in WinPE. [Here's a good article about adding MS's iSCSI Software Initiator to WinPE](http://chee-yang.blogspot.com/2011/12/waik-add-microsoft-iscsi-service-to.html). Also, what are you trying to accomplish? There may be a much easier way.

Comment: OK, yes you are right. The sanhook statement is probably not needed if I have iscsi buit-in PE image. What I'm trying to accomplish is to install Windows to iSCSI target. And I've already added iSCSI initiator to my PE. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question. Refer to the bottom of this [page](http://trentent.blogspot.com/2012/11/iscsi-ipxe-microsoft-iscsi-software.html). Still need to find out how to clear the gateway via the iPXE script.

Comment: You might be interested in this post in the iPXE forum: http://forum.ipxe.org/showthread.php?tid=6838&pid=8855#pid8855

Answer (score 0):

10.86.13.52 is your is your http server

10.86.13.149 is the IP assigned to the client by the DHCP

10.86.13.254 is the default gateway provided by the DHCP

I think you just have no network because of a driver problem

From WinPE get a console session (SHIFT+F10) and list with Notepad.exe the content of the file:

`Notepad.exe x:\Windows\inf\setupapi.app.log`

locate the section that identifies the Plug and Play ID (PnPID) of the network adapter and see if that driver is loaded ok.

Please consider even if there are no errors in the file it could still be a driver problem...

Comment: Before I try your suggestion. I did have network because I can ping the gateway.

Comment: Just checked the log, there is no network error. BTW, how can you tell which is my DHCP server?

Comment: you said you couldn't ping... I haven said the DHCP IP; I've mentioned the client IP assigned by the DHCP server and the default gateway also provided with the DHCP answer.
If you can ping then forget about a faulty driver.

Comment: Sorry for my confusing description. I said I couldn't ping iSCSI target. Forgot to mention that I could ping gateway(also the DHCP server) which is different from the tftp/http/iscsi machine.

Comment: if you can ping the gateway/dhcp server and cannot ping the iSCCI server being on the same net then forget about a routing table problem or a net driver issue.

Comment: Then how to explain my routing table that strange item?